# how to specify multi time in cron expression

Tags: cron

Is it possible to have one `cron` expression to run at `6am` and `7:30pm` every day?. I understand the following will will run `6am`, `6:30am`, `7:00pm` and `7:30pm`,

`0,30 6,19 * * *`

How will I schedule `6am` and `7:30pm` in one cron?

Comment: You can always test with [tools like this](https://crontab.guru). I don't think it's possible to have one entry with two different minute offsets.

Answer (score 0):

You can put more intelligence into the *command* that gets run, something like:

```
0,30 6,19 * * * t=T$(date +%H%M) ; [ ${t} = T0600 -o ${t} = T1930 ] && payload
```

This will actually run the `crontab` command four times a day (at 6am, 6:30am, 7pm and 7:30pm) but execute the payload *proper* only at 6am and 7:30pm as desired.

Some people opt to put this extra intelligence into a script that gets run and simply exits if the time isn't one of the desired ones, but I tend to prefer keeping all scheduling control in the `crontab` file itself.